# :first-child is too slow. Alternatives?

Tags: css

I have a div that has a few children that have borders on top and bottom. I'd like the first child and last child of that div to not have those borders. Doing `.myDiv > :first-child` is way too slow because :first-child matches all first children on the page first. I could add a `.first` class to the first element, but the children elements aren't always guaranteed to be there. There would be complicated logic to determine which is the top element.

What's the best practice for accomplishing this?

Comment: Is this a *really is too slow* situation (e.g. have an example url?) or a *hypothetically too slow* situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking that, I guess you're facing slow rendering time on your page. But I strongly believe that the cause for your slow page rendering might not be caused by the use of this pseudo selector on your CSS. There is probably much more important factors acting in the context and decreasing the overall page performance.

Are you using transparent images or elements? or maybe using pseudo selectors a lot in your JavaScript?

Comment: This may not matter at all on small websites or blogs, but poorly written / not optimised CSS can be a huge issue on more complicated ones. Especially pseudo-selectors and pseudo-elements are one of the worst when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question (it was too large for a comment), but do you really have a huge page with thousands of elements that really gives performance problems when using slow selectors? Because if that's not the case, I'd say using the `:first-child` pseudo-class is perfectly fine.

Think of all the much, much worse performance atrocities that are done using JavaScript-side DOM manipulation every day. Many jQuery selectors are a catastrophe from an optimization standpoint. Yet, the average computer power nowadays simply mitigates most performance issues.

Comment: Sadly, yes, this is going to be an application with thousands of elements, not a page. I've been happy to ignore this issue in simpler pages.

Comment: @Jason ah, okay. Then I'm afraid I think there is no better way than slapping a class on the first element or, for maximum performance, creating `id` s. That looks like shit :) but if it's a real performance issue, it might be worth it

Comment: Sadly, all CSS pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements are bad for performance, and can cause drastic decrease in speed when used on complicated websites, etc. Newer browsers tend to deal better with it but older ones like IE8 or mobile browsers on slower devices do not :(